# Hover event doesn't show changed styles in devtools, until I force hover state of devtools

Tags: html, css, devtools

I have this simple code

```
<style>input:hover{border: 3px solid blue;}</style>
<input type="text">
```

Expected behavior: when I hover the mouse over the input, new style should appear in the devtools styles section, but it only appears when I force the hover state through the devtools(not with the mouse). As I can remember it should show styles in both cases, am I wrong? This happens both in chrome and firefox devtools, so I can't really understand what is happening, I use css for 3 years and I can't remember this problem.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe Chrome shows the style until you force the `:hover` state.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most dev tools used to show hover states, but now I don't think any do (without clicking). Probably because they added support for so many element states that if they showed them all it could become confusing.